# Trading view pinescript plot my timestamp points

Tags: plot, pine-script

**Question #1**

Hello! I want to overlay  my datapoints on tradingview chart with pinescript I already have my data (order history) like:

```
0.00002609  buy 1524722057851
0.0000261   buy 1524722057851
```

Is there a chance to plot them there?

---

**Question #2**

Is there any chance to overlay my data on the embedded chart widget on my website?

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have found the solution...

> Question #1 Hello! I want to overlay my datapoints on tradingview chart with pinescript I 
>   already have my data (order history) like:

**Answer: No, I do not think there is such a thing**

> Question #2 Is there any chance to overlay my data on the embedded chart widget on my 
>   website?

**Yes, this is doable. You may need a Pro account, however. As a matter of fact, many crypto exchanges use the TV charting library to display their data. Go through the documentation here:** https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/